# How to use Infinity limits with a transformed scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a workaround for when one wants to apply geom_rect to Infinity on the y axis of a ggplot object when a transformation is applied to the y axis?

The code below does not plot the interval rectangles unless you comment out the scale_y_continuous line. When using the transformed scale, I have to put in actual data limits.  I could probably write a function to find the min/max of the other data being plotted to avoid hard coding values but I'm looking for something closer to the Inf approach.  I tried using NA instead of Inf but no luck.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    data(economics)

    ints<-data.frame(start=as.Date(paste0(seq(1970,2020,by=10),"-01-01"))) %>% 
      mutate(end=start+1785)

    plt<-ggplot(economics,aes(date,unemploy)) + theme_bw() +
      scale_y_continuous(trans="sqrt") +
      geom_rect(data=ints,inherit.aes=F,aes(xmin=start,xmax=end,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf)) + geom_line()

    plt
```

Comment: Because you can't take the square root of a negative number, it won't handle `ymin =-Inf`. Why not just set `ymin=0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
data(economics)

ints<-data.frame(start=as.Date(paste0(seq(1970,2020,by=10),"-01-01"))) %>% 
  mutate(end=start+1785)

plt<-ggplot(economics,aes(date,unemploy)) + theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="sqrt") +
  geom_rect(data=ints,inherit.aes=F,aes(xmin=start,xmax=end,ymin=0,ymax=Inf)) + geom_line()+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2000,20000)) # This will allow you to control how zoomed in you want the plot

plt
```

[image]

Comment: doh.  thanks.  i would delete my own question (or vote for it at least) if it didn't put me at risk of not being able to ask questions in the future.

Comment: Honestly, it's an obvious answer, but I'm sure this thread will be helpful for r newbies.